# Visual Studio 2010 gets stuck with solution with MVC3 Razor and Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, razor

I've a solution with several .dll projects, an Asp.NET MVC3 Razor project and an Cloud project.

If I try to compile the solution with the Cloud project loaded, VS2010 gets stuck in "Buil started".

I have to forcefully close VS2010 killing the process and restart. Then the compiling works good once, the next time it will get stuck again.

If I unload the project and set the mvc project as start-up, everything works (but azure of course).

What could be the problem?

Cheers.

Comment: Attach a second copy of VS to the frozen instance and pause it in the debugger.  What is it doing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you had any luck with this?

Comment: nope, it happens randomly. At this moment I'm keeping the cloud project unloaded, but I have to face the issue shortly, so I'll put here any progress.

Answer (score 2):

Was it by any chance an ASP.NET MVC project to which you added a `CloudService` project later on or did you start off with a `CloudService` from the very beginning?

I was in the former situation and I had no end of problems, like not being able to open property pages or deploying the application. It's not quite your issue, but the following article might help:

http://tomkrueger.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/azure-deployment-issue-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2010-and-net-4-0/

As I say, my problems started because I actually added an Azure project to an existing ASP.NET MVC solution and there were some unnecessary settings left over in the `web.csproj` file.

All I had to do was open `web.csproj` in notepad and remove all occurrences of the `<PlatformTarget>` element.

My MVC prjoject was x86 and of course Azure works on x64 only. Even though I had the platform target set up as `AnyCPU` somehow Azure couldn't quite get along with it.

Maybe cleaning up your project files helps as well.

Comment: Humm... I'd removed, added, moved and everything possible and now it's working and it doesn't get stuck anymore. I have checked what you say, and there is no one of those <PlatformTarget>, so probably they have been deleted in the process and for that reason now works. I'm gonna test for a couple of days and ensure it works, but I'm almost sure you are definitely right and that was the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @vtortola - Happy you could (apparently) solve it. It gave me a headache for months so I hope you can be spared that suffering ;)

Comment: As soon as I talk it gets stuck again :(

Comment: @vtorola - Have you tried doing a `Clean solution` after the other "clean up"? Maybe something is being held up.

Comment: Apparently it is related with the unitary tests projects ¬¬. Still trying to find out...